# CMD как изменить отображение пути

Tags: cmd

Допустим я хочу скрыть отображение пути в консоли windows 10, чтобы, к примеру, вместо C:/Users/user/some_folder было просто > , но по факту путь был C:/Users/user/some_folder. Помню как-то делал одной командой, но уже не помню как

Comment: Команда `prompt` или одноимённая переменная окружения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно выполнить команду:

```
prompt $g
```

P.S.
См. справку:

```
prompt /?
```